# finding arraylist size with out access to size method

Tags: java, arraylist

If we were trying to find the size of an arraylist(this is not the regular arraylist its a custom one, important methods below) without having access to the .size() method, how would we go about doing that?

The arraylist class has a .hasNext()and .next() method

the .hasNext() method tells if there is another element left in the list

the .next() method moves to the next element in the list

If it were a linkedList I would just start at the head and use the .hasNext() and .next() method in a loop to count the size. But there is no head in an arraylist and I think that is my main problem.

I came up with this but I don't think its right.

```
public int getSize(SomeArrayList<String> list){
    int size=0;
    for(int i=0;list.get(i).hasNext();i++){
       size++;}
    return size;
```

Comment: just asking, why would you not use `.size()`?

Comment: `java.util.List` has no methods named `hasNext` or `next`, while `java.util.Iterator` has.

Comment: @Perneel homework assignment.

Comment: Has next is a method on get()? Seems odd, since that's a String, in your example. Does your code compile?

Comment: In java 8 you can do something like `list.stream().count()`

Answer (score 3):

```
list.toArray().length
```

will do the trick.

Comment: I actually did this for a problem earlier, I don't know why I didn't think of it... we probably won't be allowed to do it though.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code :

```
public int getSize(ArrayList<String> list) {
    int i = 0;
    for(String s : list) {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try To use this code:

```
 int size = 0;
    Iterator<String> it =list.iterator(); 
    while (it.hasNext()){
      it.next();
     size++;
    }
    return size;
```

Comment: if the list has a hasNext method in it why do we do list.iterator() ?

Comment: @Sladkomu List-interface doesn't have .hasNext()

Comment: btw, you have to call the .next() function in the loop, so you will actually go to the next element. Otherwise you will produce infinite loop

Comment: @JohnnyAW: Yes you are right. I have changed my example.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this?

```
int size = 0;
try{
    while(true){
        list.get(size);
        size++;
    }
} catch(IndexOutOfBoundException e){
}
```

if you will go out of bound, exception will be thrown and you will get your size without any .size() .length

Comment: Wow taking advantage of Exception(s) :)

Comment: @Vishrant i'm actually not 100% sure, if they already know exceptions...:)

Comment: why down-vote? it will work and it doesn't use .size() function, so it is valid solution!

Answer (score 0):

In your code `list.get(i).hasNext()` smells. You haven't mentioned is there a `get(int index)` method but if we assumes there is, it should return with a String object which has no `hasNext()` method. Your loop could look like this:

`while (list.hasNext()){
  size++;
  list.next();
}`

I'd do a null check first and it is not clear for me how can you satisfy that the list is not empty at the beginning.

Your data structure is quite strange for me since it looks more like an iterator not a real list.